# access proxied method within a proxied class

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

Hi I was thinking about such case:

```
 public class MyService {

        private IList<Entity> data;

        public virtual IList<Entity> GetData()
        {
            return data;
        }        

        public virtual IList<Entity> GetDataAdvanced()
        {
           return GetData();
        }
  }
```

Consider a situation when i have a proxy of this class (e.g logging interceptor). The problem is: with GetData() method will GetDataAdvanced() use: the proxied one or normal? After a test i looks like it is not using proxy. I was wondering if it is possible to change such behavior ?

Thanks for help.

Kuba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends. When you're using `ProxyGenerator.CreateClassProxy()` or `ProxyGenerator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithoutTarget()`, the proxy will be a child class of your original class which is instantiated and then, yes, `GetData()` will actually call the proxy.

If you however are using `ProxyGenerator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithTarget()` and you're providing your own instance of `MyService`, the proxy is only a wrapper from the outside and internal calls like the `GetData()` call will not go through the proxy.

Comment: thx - good to know that, one more thing - is there any way to specify what proxy generation strategy to use (without or with target) when registering componenets with windsor container ?

Comment: Sorry, no experience with Windsor.